# Convolutional layer output size

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to get into deep learning and I have a minor problem in understanding concerning CNNs.

According to [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks), the common formula for computing the output size of a conv. layer is `W'=(W−F+2P)/S+1`, where `W` is the input size, `F` is the receptive field, `P` is the padding and `S` is the stride. So far so good and I can perfectly comprehend that formula.

But then there's the [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros#first_convolutional_layer). According to the tutorial, the output size of the first convolutional layer is 28x28x32. Why not (28–5)/1 + 1 = 24 → 24x24x32 so that the first pooling layer would reduce it to 12x12x32? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here for the conv layer by default they used `SAME` padding. `P=floor(F/2)` for `SAME` padding. So `(28- 5 + 2*2)/1 +1 = 28`

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I was assuming that `SAME` stands for a padding of one, without looking it up.